# Qemu permision denied, but using sudo

Tags: permissions, qemu, elf

I tried loading a i386 firmware file and its also distributed as an elf file,
but executing

```
sudo qemu-i386 file.elf
Error while loading file.elf: Permission denied
```

How do I get more information why permissions denied? even as the user root, i get the same message. Did the file try to load an resource that is blocked?

The bin file seems to be a mbr snipped, so I might be able to write it to a virtual disk, but the elf file seemed more appropriate. getting it to run is ok, but the error message, how do I learn more about this, why maybe?

The binary file (mbr) succesfully boots from a (virtual) harddisk.
the elf file file information:

```
file.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), statically linked, not stripped
```

**clue**
the output of ls -l file.elf:

```
$ ls -l file.elf
-rw-r--r-- 1 me me 512058 Sep 28 10:47 file.elf
```

chmod +x did the trick.

Comment: Try `chmod +x file.elf` or `chmod +r file.elf`

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `ls -l file.elf`.

Comment: Permissions, a classic mistake. Thanks Gagan and AdminBee, both the hint and solution. If only these where answers, i could upvote.